# Is there any way to skip some documents in GeoNear() MongoDB method?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Lets say I have collection of documents with specified longitude and latitude.

```
type is specified:

{
    id: ObjectId,
    location : {double, double}, /*array, that contains
                                   just longitude and latitude*/
    someUsefulData : string
}
```

I need to get all documents, that located in 50 miles area around some location. For this purpose I'm using such method:

```
// set GetNear() options
var options = new GeoNearOptionsBuilder()
    .SetMaxDistance(50) // meens 50 miles
    .SetSpherical(true);

// create conditions query
var conditions = Query.NE("someUsefulData ", $ne : {null});

// execute GetNear()
var geoNearResult = collection
    .GeoNear(conditions, longitude, latitude, limit, options);
```

This part works well.

But.

I need to skip some result from the very beginning - for classic paging implementation. Maybe, someone know how to do this, considering the fact that GeoNear() returns GeoNearResult - which is NOT a MongoCursor, so I can't use SetSkip(20), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting the limit to limit+20 and skipping the first 20 documents in your application. Also, you can vote for https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3925 which would add a native skip option to the geoNear command.

Comment: As I know, geoNear doesn't return cursor, but returns data. So after executing this command whole amount of data specified in limit will be loaded from db.
Am I wrong?

Comment: By the way, thanks for link, it's what I needed. So now I know for sure that there is no way to simple skip in geoNear.